# Interface Inherited declaration

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, zope.interface

I'm trying to use an old code which has been developed by a Github developer. The code uses implements in zope.interface library to declare interfaces on a class's elements. Since implements in the library doesn't work anymore at Python 3.6, I confront with this error:

```
TypeError: Class advice impossible in Python3.  Use the @implementer class decorator instead.
```

Several websites have explained how to substitute implements with @implementer to work at Python 3.6, like [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/73114/zope.interface.implementer). But I haven't found any example to explain how to update the code when zope.interface.implements has been used as an inheritance. The code looks like this:

```
from zope.interface import implements
class Car(implements(Moveable)):
     def __init__(self, x, v, lane, model: IDM, lane_change: LaneChange,
             length):
...
```

I would like to update this code to work at Python 3.6. I've tried this

```
@implementer(Moveable) 
class Car:
     def __init__(self, x, v, lane, model: IDM, lane_change: LaneChange,
             length):
```

but it does n't work. 
Please help me to figure out how to make the above code running in Python 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below steps solved the issue for me,

```
pip uninstall apex
git clone https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex
cd apex
python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 2):

To use implementer instead of implements as suggested by Python, you need to import it as well opposed to importing implements

```
from zope.interface import implementer
```

In your code it shows you are still using implements, that seems to be the problem according to provided information. Hope it helps.